# How do I integrate google marketplace xml feed

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I don't know where to start integrating google marketplace can anyone help me. I will map the xml to our API so I was wondering how would I do that if I don't know where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Google Apps Marketplace documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/intro) provides some information on how to get started.